# Input comparison does not work properly, always going to the failure case, why?

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, scanf

In my C program, I am trying to use `scanf` to get the string (`char*`) input from the console, however, the input always then turns into the value `1638238`, whatever is inputted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    for(;;){
        printf("Choose your option:\n-d for decryption\n-e for encryption\n");
        char command[2];
        char* input = command;
        scanf("%s", input);
        if(command == "-d"){
            printf("Please enter the path of the file\n");
            // decrypt
        }
        else if(command == "-e"){
            printf("Please enter the path of the file\n");
            // encrypt
        }
        else{
            printf("Unrecognized command '%d'\n", command);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

> input: -e
>
> output: Unrecognized command '1638238'

Compiler: Tiny C

---

**Edit:** I can input anything, and it outputs

> Please enter the path of the file to decrypted`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
    for(;;){
        printf("Choose your option:\n-d for decryption\n-e for encryption\n");
        char command[3];
        char* input = command;
        scanf("%s", input);
        if(strcmp(input, "-d")){
            printf("Please enter the path of the file to be decrypted\n");
        }
        else if(strcmp(input, "-e")){
            printf("Please enter the path of the file to be encrypted\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Unrecognized command '%d'\n", input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `strcmp` to compare of string. and `char command[3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(command == "-d")`. Not at all.

`command` refers to the base address of the array. What you want is to compare the *content* of those arrays, not their `address` location.

you might want to use `strcmp()`. Check [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

word of caution: to use a `char` array as string, you need to have a terminating `\0` [`NULL`] character. use `char command[3];` instead.

---

EDIT:

To address the issue in the updated code, <sup>(copied into the answer from the comments below)</sup>

1. `strcmp()` returns `0` in case of match. So, to determine the "matching condition", you need to use `if (!strcmp(str1,str2))` form (note the `!`).
2. To avoid the possibility of buffer overflow by lengthier input, limit the input to `scanf()` by using

   ```
   scanf("%2s", input);  //when input is a 3 element char array
   ```
3. I hope you do realize that your `for(;;)` loop is an absolute infinite loop, as you don't have any `break`ing statement. Try to add one, based on your convenient logic.

Comment: I have edited my answer due to another problem which has occurred using `strcmp`. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: @Joe `-d` or `-e` will go to last `else`, `Unrecognized command` , all the other input will take you to `Please enter the path of the file to be decrypted`. guess that's not what you want. maybe use `!` with `strcmp` ?

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings use `strcmp`. `command == "-e"` is a wrong way to compare. `command` decays to a pointer to the first element of your input. By doing `command == "-e"`, you are comparing a pointer with a string.